# Searching for an Object inside the JSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Here is my JSON String. Now i want to search for name in this JSON and then display the results...

Comment: image name? text name? or window name?

Comment: Any names... out of this entire json object

Comment: please clarify your purpose with some code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Iterate through the keys:
(enhancement to Amit Gupta's answer)

```
var result = [];
getNames(data, "name");
document.write("result: " + result.join(", "));

function getNames(obj, name) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if ("object" == typeof(obj[key])) {
                getNames(obj[key], name);
            } else if (key == name) {
                result.push(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/JFEMH/

```js
const data = {
  "widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
      "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
      "name": "main_window",
      "width": 500,
      "height": 500
    },
    "image": {
      "src": "Images/Sun.png",
      "name": "sun1",
      "hOffset": 250,
      "vOffset": 250,
      "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
      "data": "Click Here",
      "size": 36,
      "style": "bold",
      "name": "text1",
      "hOffset": 250,
      "vOffset": 100,
      "alignment": "center",
      "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
  }
}

let result = [];
getNames(data, "title");
document.write("result: " + result.join(", "));

function getNames(obj, name) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if ("object" == typeof(obj[key])) {
        getNames(obj[key], name);
      } else if (key == name) {
        result.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed a little for return function: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/qtm8302e/

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jquery to parse JSON

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../JSON Source",
    success: function(msg) {
    var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    if(obj.debug== "on"){
        //do anything
```

.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate recursively to all the objects inside the given object.

```
    s = "";

    function recursiveSearch(obj, name){
       if(typeof(obj)==="object" {
         for(var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              s += ":" + recursiveSearch(obj[key], name);
            }  
       } else if( typeof(obj["name"] != 'undefined') {
         s += ":" + obj["name"];

    }
```

Output will be colon separated values with key "name"

Comment: Note in this case if "name" is of object type they will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this JSON extension [injson](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/injson) .  It allows for you to use JQuery to search for a key in a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing custom search functions, you can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) which enables queries on JSON structures with XPath expressions. Example:

```
    var data = {
     "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
           "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
           "name": "main_window",
           "width": 500,
           "height": 500
        },
        "image": {
           "src": "Images/Sun.png",
           "name": "sun1",
           "hOffset": 250,
           "vOffset": 250,
           "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
           "data": "Click Here",
           "size": 36,
           "style": "bold",
           "name": "text1",
           "hOffset": 250,
           "vOffset": 100,
           "alignment": "center",
           "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
     }
  },
res = JSON.search( data, '//image[name]' );

console.log( res[0].name );
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/CRTz9/

DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with the method "search" and returns an array with the matches (empty array if no matches were found).

Comment: That isn't a working fiddle, at least not anymore. It doesn't appear that the Fiddle includes the `DefiantJS` library: `TypeError: JSON.search is not a function`

Comment: @cjbarth Since my original post, I've updated the site of https://defiantjs.com. When doing this, I forgot to add defiant-lib on my server (at least the old path), consequently, the path from JsFiddle is invalid. I have updated the path to correct one and re-saved the fiddle and now it works as it should. Thank you for the "heads up" and sorry for the broken link :-)

Meanwhile, the DefiantJS website is up to date and has both documentation as well as testing area that might be useful.