# How to extract a json object that's inside a json object

Tags: javascript, json

Convert this:

```
{"items":[{"id":"BLE89-A0-123-384","weight":"100","quantity":3},
          ...    
          {"id":"BLE10-A0-123-321","weight":"100","quantity":4}],
"country":"JUS",
"region":"A",
...
"timeout":"FILLER"}
```

To this:

`{"BLE89-A0-123-384": "3", "BLE10-A0-123-321": "4"}` that is... {id: quantity}

I found an answer that almost does what I need: [Searching for an Object inside the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110327/searching-for-an-object-inside-the-json). But that answer doesn't help me because it's only at the first level (one json object). My problem is at the second level (json object within a json object). Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{"BLE89-A0-123-384", "3";  "BLE10-A0-123-321", "4"}` That's not even a valid object, it needs to be a key value pair.

Comment: What *don't* you know how to do? Do you know how to access a member of an Array or Object? Do you know how to iterate an Array? Do you know how to create an object, and assign it new key/value pairs? It would be good to know exactly what you need help with.

Comment: @am not i am ... I didn't know what path I had to take to get from start to finish.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It helps if you don't think of JSON objects as JSON objects.  Once you run a JSON string through JSON.parse, it is a native JavaScript object.

In JavaScript, there are two ways to access objects.

## Dot Notation

The dot notation goes like this

`myObject.name`

See the dot? You can use that to access any object *property* (which indeed may be another object in javascript, as long as it has a valid dot notation name).  You can't use characters like `-`, `.`, and the space character.

## Bracket Notation (may be another name)

`myObject["variableName"]`

Like dot notation but allows some other characters, like `-` and the space character..  Does exactly the same thing.

Using these notations is useful because we can access nested properties.

`myObj.foo.bar.baz()`

Now let's get to your JSON object...

`{"items":[{"id":"BLE89-A0-123-384","weight":"100","quantity":3,"stock":0},

          {"id":"BLE10-A0-123-321","weight":"100","quantity":4,"stock":0}],`

You might want to brush up on the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/) yourself, but in your example, here's a few clues...

`{` Means the start of an object.  (Keep in mind your entire JSON string is an object itself.)

`}` Means the end of an object.

`"variable"` (with quotes! important in JSON, but not when accessing/declaring javascript objects) assigns a property to your object.

`:` Is the assignment operator in both JSON and JavaScript objects.
Anything to the right of the `:` is the value you are assigning to the property on the left.

`,` Means you are starting a new property within an object.

You probably know that `[]` with `,` commas inside means an array.

When we run your string through `JSON.parse(string)`, we'll get an object that looks like this...

`var myResponse = JSON.parse(response);`

You can now use it as a native JavaScript object.  What you're looking for is a nested property within "items".

`var items = myResponse.items; //alternatively you could just use myResponse.items`

Since `items` is an *array of objects*, we'll need to iterate through it in order to convert the existing object into a new object.

```
var i;
var result = {} ; //declare a new object.
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var objectInResponse = items[i]; //get current object
    var id = objectInResponse.id; //extract the id.
    var quantity = objectInResponse.quantity;
    result[id] = quantity; //use bracket notation to assign "BLE89-A0-123-384"
    //instead of id.  Bracket notation allows you to use the value
    // of a variable for the property name.
```

Result is now an object that looks like:

```
{
    "BLE89-A0-123-384" : 3, //additional properties designated by comma
    "BLE10-A0-123-321" : 4 // The last key/value in an object literal CANNOT
    // have a comma after it!
}
```

You can access the properties using bracket notation.

`var BLE89 = result["BLE10-A0-123-321"]; //use quotes, otherwise JavaScript will try to look up the value of a variable.`

Comment: Wow, that's a much more thorough answer than i expected for the question :D

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
var obj = {
    "items":[
        {"id":"BLE89-A0-123-384","weight":"100","quantity":3},
        {"id":"BLE10-A0-123-321","weight":"100","quantity":4}
    ],
    "country":"JUS",
    "region":"A",
    "timeout":"FILLER"
};

var quantities = {};
obj.items.forEach(function (item) {
    quantities[item.id] = item.quantity;
});
```

`quantities` will then be the object `{"BLE89-A0-123-384":3,"BLE10-A0-123-321":4}`. [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a native method of array objects in JavaScript that lets you iterate through their elements. You may want to put that piece of code inside a function:

```
function getQuantities(obj) {
    var quantities = {};
    obj.items.forEach(function (item) {
        quantities[item.id] = item.quantity;
    });
    return quantities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
var newJSON = {};
for (var i = 0; i < oldJSON.items.length; i++) {
  newJSON[oldJSON.items[i].id] = oldJSON.items[i].quantity;
}
```

Comment: `.length()` needs to be `.length`. Length is a property not a function.