# Json parsing in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

i need to parse the following json response.

```
{
"attrs": {
    "width": 578,
    "height": 200
},
"nodeType": "Stage",
"children": [
    {
        "attrs": {},
        "nodeType": "Layer",
        "children": [
            {
                "attrs": {
                    "x": 289,
                    "y": 100,
                    "sides": 6,
                    "radius": 70,
                    "fill": "red",
                    "stroke": "black",
                    "strokeWidth": 4
                },
                "nodeType": "Shape",
                "shapeType": "RegularPolygon"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

for any help thanks..

Comment: Where are you getting this json response from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we can easily parse using `JSON.parse(YOUR-JSON-STRING)`

```
var jsonStr = '{ "attrs": { "width": 578, "height": 200 }, "nodeType": "Stage", "children": [ { "attrs": {}, "nodeType": "Layer", "children": [ { "attrs": { "x": 289, "y": 100, "sides": 6, "radius": 70, "fill": "red", "stroke": "black", "strokeWidth": 4 }, "nodeType": "Shape", "shapeType": "RegularPolygon" } ] } ] }';
```

putting it all together finall solution would be something like below

```
var jsonStr = '{ "attrs": { "width": 578, "height": 200 }, "nodeType": "Stage", "children": [ { "attrs": {}, "nodeType": "Layer", "children": [ { "attrs": { "x": 289, "y": 100, "sides": 6, "radius": 70, "fill": "red", "stroke": "black", "strokeWidth": 4 }, "nodeType": "Shape", "shapeType": "RegularPolygon" } ] } ] }';

var parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
alert(parsedData.attrs.width)


$.each(parsedData.children, function (index, value) {
    $.each(this.children, function (index, value) {
        $('#mydata').append(' x value is : '+this.attrs.x);
        $('#mydata').append(' y value is : '+this.attrs.y);
    });
    console.log(this);
});
```

here is a live example http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/bMHN8/

Comment: consider accepting it as correct answer if it helped you out.

Comment: yeah....do u have any idea how to represent this parsed data in xml tags showing parent and child nodes

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do it, but you can check the xml syntax and build smoething out of the parsed values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = '{ "attrs": { "width": 578, "height": 200 }, "nodeType": "Stage", "children": [ { "attrs": {}, "nodeType": "Layer", "children": [ { "attrs": { "x": 289, "y": 100, "sides": 6, "radius": 70, "fill": "red", "stroke": "black", "strokeWidth": 4 }, "nodeType": "Shape", "shapeType": "RegularPolygon" } ] } ] }';

 var _json = JSON.parse(data);


    console.log(_json.attrs.width);
```

if you are retrieving JSON via Ajax in jQuery you can do:

```
 $.ajax({
    /* Set the JSON datatype in ajax call*/
    dataType:'json',
    ...
/* get json in response and you already have it "parsed" */
     success:function(json){

     console.log(json.attrs.width);
    }
    ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`parseJSON` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
```

If you make an AJAX call to fetch the data, specify the JSON data type, and the response will be parsed automatically for you:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "jsondata",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(obj) {
    alert(obj.nodeType);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dot notation, you can access the properties and objects of your JSON data.

Firstly, assign your JSON response to a variable, e.g.

```
var json = { "attrs": { "width": 578, "height": 200 }, "nodeType": "Stage", "children": [ { "attrs": {}, "nodeType": "Layer", "children": [ { "attrs": { "x": 289, "y": 100, "sides": 6, "radius": 70, "fill": "red", "stroke": "black", "strokeWidth": 4 }, "nodeType": "Shape", "shapeType": "RegularPolygon" } ] } ] }
```

Example, to get the width of the JSON data object and display it via the console:

```
console.log(json.attrs['width']);
```

Returns: **578**

And then to get the nested objects values, e.g.

```
console.log(json.children[0].children[0].attrs);
```

Returns: an object with the x, y, sides, radius, etc. properties.

To access these, e.g.

```
console.log(json.children[0].children[0].attrs['radius']);
```

Returns: **70**

There is a more general answer to the dot and bracket notation/syntax here: [How to extract a json object that's inside a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368171/how-to-extract-a-json-object-thats-inside-a-json-object)