# Issue manipulating XML into JSON and displaying specific element in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, express

I am trying to manipulate XML data coming from an html.request. I have the request setup correctly and the response is in correct XML. (This is output from "console.log(soapreplyx);" in my script below.)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:listCssResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">
            <return>
                <css uuid="{CA14384C-D04D-39D0-2BAF-01EEDD8E9914}">
                    <description/>
                    <clause>AllPhones</clause>
                    <name>SUBSCRIBE</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{97FE9A56-85D7-8198-805C-925E2FB264DD}">
                    <description>CSS for Unity Connection SIP Trunk</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-Unity</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{1D61F1AD-8E1C-DC71-C9AD-E37B85DE0F9C}">
                    <description>Internal Only</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-Internal</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{C09EDFA7-4BF7-AF15-483D-54F0D07666A1}">
                    <description>Inbound CSS for Gateways</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-Gateways</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{A2BF1C5E-6685-D33A-D8BB-037F4D211DC9}">
                    <description>Local, Internal, and Emergency</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-PSTN-Sim-Local</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{DF03B400-DA2D-29A7-6460-D0B72D578CD7}">
                    <description>LD, Local, Internal, and Emergency</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:LAB-PSTN-Sim-LD:Blocked:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-PSTN-Sim-LD</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{F4626B2A-E3F6-6BF0-78E7-CBB6123091CB}">
                    <description>Intl, LD, Local, Internal, and Emergency</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:Blocked:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:LAB-PSTN-Sim-LD:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Intl:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-PSTN-Sim-Intl</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{70E8D03E-623E-354C-991D-9FB392747291}">
                    <description>Inbound Transform Calling</description>
                    <clause>LAB-Tansform-Calling</clause>
                    <name>CSS-LAB-Transform-Calling</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{5FD922AD-9A14-FD17-ACBF-8FAAF2B7326F}">
                    <description>CSS for UCCX Port Group</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Agents:Unity_Connection:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-UCCX</name>
                </css>
            </return>
        </ns:listCssResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to turn parts of that XML data into JSON so that I can reference them in an HTML table. This is where I am getting into hot water. I'm using the library "camaro" to help me work with the data and get it into JSON. Here is what my output looks like from that. (This is output from "console.log(json);" in my script below.)

```
{ css:
   [ '': { cssdescription: 'CSS for UCCX Port Group',
       cssname: 'CSS-UCCX',
       csspartitions: 'AllPhones:Agents:Unity_Connection:UCCX' } ] }
```

This is my script:

```
// MODULES - INCLUDES
var transform = require('camaro');

module.exports = function (app) {
  // FORM - SUBMIT - CUCMMAPPER
  app.post('/cucmmapper/submit', function (req, res) {

    // FORM - DATA COLLECTION
    var cucmpub = req.body.cucmpub;
    var cucmversion = req.body.cucmversion;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // JS - VARIABLE DEFINITION
    var authentication = username + ":" + password;
    var soapreplyx = '';
    var cssx = '';
    var spacer = '--------';

    // HTTP.REQUEST - BUILD CALL
    var https = require("https");
    var headers = {
      'SoapAction': 'CUCM:DB ver=' + cucmversion + ' listCss',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authentication).toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    };

    // SOAP - AXL CALL
    var soapBody = new Buffer('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">' +
      '<soapenv:Header/>' +
      '<soapenv:Body>' +
      '<ns:listCss sequence="?">' +
      '<searchCriteria>' +
      '<name>%</name>' +
      '</searchCriteria>' +
      '<returnedTags uuid="?">' +
      '<name>?</name>' +
      '<description>?</description>' +
      '<clause>?</clause>' +
      '</returnedTags>' +
      '</ns:listCss>' +
      '</soapenv:Body>' +
      '</soapenv:Envelope>');

    // HTTP.REQUEST - OPTIONS
    var options = {
      host: cucmpub, // IP ADDRESS OF CUCM PUBLISHER
      port: 8443, // DEFAULT CISCO SSL PORT
      path: '/axl/', // AXL URL
      method: 'POST', // AXL REQUIREMENT OF POST
      headers: headers, // HEADER VAR
      rejectUnauthorized: false // REQUIRED TO ACCEPT SELF-SIGNED CERTS
    };

    // HTTP.REQUEST - Doesn't seem to need this line, but it might be useful anyway for pooling?
    options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

    // HTTP.REQUEST - OPEN SESSION
    let soapRequest = https.request(options, soapResponse => {
      soapResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
      soapResponse.on('data', chunk => {
        soapreplyx += chunk
      });
      // HTTP.REQUEST - RESULTS + RENDER
      soapResponse.on('end', () => {
        console.log(soapreplyx);
        console.log(spacer);
        const json = transform(soapreplyx, {
          css: ['//css', {
              cssname: 'name',
              cssdescription: 'description',
              csspartitions: 'clause'
          }]
        });
        console.log(json);
        console.log(spacer);
        var cssx = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(cssx.cssname);
        res.render('cucmmapper-results.html', {
          title: 'CUCM 2.1',
          soapreply: soapreplyx,
          cucmpub: cucmpub,
          css: cssx
        });
      });
    });

    // SOAP - SEND AXL CALL
    soapRequest.write(soapBody);
    soapRequest.end();
  });
}
```

I am trying to follow this previously posted question's answer. [How to extract a json object that's inside a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368171/how-to-extract-a-json-object-thats-inside-a-json-object) I think I'm close, but suspect my JSON data isn't quite right and am unsure how to fix it.

I am still new to JS/Node/Express. I appreciate any help or direction anyone can give. Thanks y'all!

Comment: What would you like the extracted JSON to look like?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it should look like this:

{ css:
   [ { cssdescription: 'CSS for UCCX Port Group',
       cssname: 'CSS-UCCX',
       csspartitions: 'AllPhones:Agents:Unity_Connection:UCCX' } ] }

It is a very subtle difference with the '': removed from in front of {cssdescription. I don't know if that makes a difference when trying to reference that. I need to be able to pick out say "cssname" and put all the values into an HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to move back to xml2js and remove some offending lines of the XML output that I was getting instead and it worked really well. Here is my code.

```
// MODULES - INCLUDES
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

module.exports = function (app) {
  // FORM - SUBMIT - CUCMMAPPER
  app.post('/cucmmapper/submit', function (req, res) {

    // FORM - DATA COLLECTION
    var cucmpub = req.body.cucmpub;
    var cucmversion = req.body.cucmversion;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // JS - VARIABLE DEFINITION
    var authentication = username + ":" + password;
    var soapreplyx = '';
    var cssx = '';
    var spacer = '-----';
    var rmline1 = '';
    var rmline2 = '';
    var rmline3 = '';
    var rmline4 = '';
    var rmbottomup1 = '';
    var rmbottomup2 = '';
    var rmbottomup3 = '';

    // HTTP.REQUEST - BUILD CALL
    var https = require("https");
    var headers = {
      'SoapAction': 'CUCM:DB ver=' + cucmversion + ' listCss',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authentication).toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    };

    // SOAP - AXL CALL
    var soapBody = new Buffer('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">' +
      '<soapenv:Header/>' +
      '<soapenv:Body>' +
      '<ns:listCss sequence="?">' +
      '<searchCriteria>' +
      '<name>%</name>' +
      '</searchCriteria>' +
      '<returnedTags uuid="?">' +
      '<name>?</name>' +
      '<description>?</description>' +
      '<clause>?</clause>' +
      '</returnedTags>' +
      '</ns:listCss>' +
      '</soapenv:Body>' +
      '</soapenv:Envelope>');

    // HTTP.REQUEST - OPTIONS
    var options = {
      host: cucmpub, // IP ADDRESS OF CUCM PUBLISHER
      port: 8443, // DEFAULT CISCO SSL PORT
      path: '/axl/', // AXL URL
      method: 'POST', // AXL REQUIREMENT OF POST
      headers: headers, // HEADER VAR
      rejectUnauthorized: false // REQUIRED TO ACCEPT SELF-SIGNED CERTS
    };

    // HTTP.REQUEST - Doesn't seem to need this line, but it might be useful anyway for pooling?
    options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

    // HTTP.REQUEST - OPEN SESSION
    let soapRequest = https.request(options, soapResponse => {
      soapResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
      soapResponse.on('data', chunk => {
        soapreplyx += chunk
      });
      // HTTP.REQUEST - RESULTS + RENDER
      soapResponse.on('end', () => {

        // EDIT - SCRUB XML OUTPUT
        var rmline1 = soapreplyx.replace(/<\?xml\sversion='1\.0'\sencoding='utf-8'\?>/g, '');
        var rmline2 = rmline1.replace(/<soapenv:Envelope\sxmlns:soapenv="http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/">/g, '');
        var rmline3 = rmline2.replace(/<soapenv:Body>/g, '');
        var rmline4 = rmline3.replace(/<ns:listCssResponse\sxmlns:ns="http:\/\/www\.cisco\.com\/AXL\/API\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]">/g, '');
        var rmbottomup1 = rmline4.replace(/<\/soapenv:Envelope>/g, '');
        var rmbottomup2 = rmbottomup1.replace(/<\/soapenv:Body>/g, '');
        var xmlscrubbed = rmbottomup2.replace(/<\/ns:listCssResponse>/g, '');
        // console.log(xmlscrubbed);
        // console.log(spacer);

        // XML2JS - TESTING
        parser.parseString(xmlscrubbed, function (err, result) {
          var cssx = result['return']['css'];
        //   console.log(cssx);
        //   console.log(spacer);
          res.render('cucmmapper-results.html', {
            title: 'CUCM 2.0',
            cucmpub: cucmpub,
            cssx: cssx,
            soapreply: soapreplyx,
            xmlscrubbed: xmlscrubbed
          });
        });
      });
    });

    // SOAP - SEND AXL CALL
    soapRequest.write(soapBody);
    soapRequest.end();
  });
}
```

I end up getting perfect JSON that I can use just fine. Thank everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const xml =`
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:listCssResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">
            <return>
                <css uuid="{CA14384C-D04D-39D0-2BAF-01EEDD8E9914}">
                    <description/>
                    <clause>AllPhones</clause>
                    <name>SUBSCRIBE</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{97FE9A56-85D7-8198-805C-925E2FB264DD}">
                    <description>CSS for Unity Connection SIP Trunk</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-Unity</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{1D61F1AD-8E1C-DC71-C9AD-E37B85DE0F9C}">
                    <description>Internal Only</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-Internal</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{C09EDFA7-4BF7-AF15-483D-54F0D07666A1}">
                    <description>Inbound CSS for Gateways</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-Gateways</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{A2BF1C5E-6685-D33A-D8BB-037F4D211DC9}">
                    <description>Local, Internal, and Emergency</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-PSTN-Sim-Local</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{DF03B400-DA2D-29A7-6460-D0B72D578CD7}">
                    <description>LD, Local, Internal, and Emergency</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:LAB-PSTN-Sim-LD:Blocked:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-PSTN-Sim-LD</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{F4626B2A-E3F6-6BF0-78E7-CBB6123091CB}">
                    <description>Intl, LD, Local, Internal, and Emergency</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Unity_Connection:Blocked:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:LAB-PSTN-Sim-LD:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Intl:Agents:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-PSTN-Sim-Intl</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{70E8D03E-623E-354C-991D-9FB392747291}">
                    <description>Inbound Transform Calling</description>
                    <clause>LAB-Tansform-Calling</clause>
                    <name>CSS-LAB-Transform-Calling</name>
                </css>
                <css uuid="{5FD922AD-9A14-FD17-ACBF-8FAAF2B7326F}">
                    <description>CSS for UCCX Port Group</description>
                    <clause>AllPhones:Agents:Unity_Connection:UCCX</clause>
                    <name>CSS-UCCX</name>
                </css>
            </return>
        </ns:listCssResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
`

const { css } = transform(xml, {
  css: ['//css', {
    uuid: '@uuid',
    description: 'description',
    clause: 'clause',
    name: 'name',
  }]
})

console.log(css)
```

Output

```
[ { clause: 'AllPhones',
    description: '',
    name: 'SUBSCRIBE',
    uuid: '{CA14384C-D04D-39D0-2BAF-01EEDD8E9914}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Unity_Connection:UCCX',
    description: 'CSS for Unity Connection SIP Trunk',
    name: 'CSS-Unity',
    uuid: '{97FE9A56-85D7-8198-805C-925E2FB264DD}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Unity_Connection:Agents:UCCX',
    description: 'Internal Only',
    name: 'CSS-Internal',
    uuid: '{1D61F1AD-8E1C-DC71-C9AD-E37B85DE0F9C}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Unity_Connection:UCCX',
    description: 'Inbound CSS for Gateways',
    name: 'CSS-Gateways',
    uuid: '{C09EDFA7-4BF7-AF15-483D-54F0D07666A1}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Unity_Connection:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:Agents:UCCX',
    description: 'Local, Internal, and Emergency',
    name: 'CSS-PSTN-Sim-Local',
    uuid: '{A2BF1C5E-6685-D33A-D8BB-037F4D211DC9}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Unity_Connection:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:LAB-PSTN-Sim-LD:Blocked:Agents:UCCX',
    description: 'LD, Local, Internal, and Emergency',
    name: 'CSS-PSTN-Sim-LD',
    uuid: '{DF03B400-DA2D-29A7-6460-D0B72D578CD7}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Unity_Connection:Blocked:LAB-PSTN-Sim-911:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Local:LAB-PSTN-Sim-LD:LAB-PSTN-Sim-Intl:Agents:UCCX',
    description: 'Intl, LD, Local, Internal, and Emergency',
    name: 'CSS-PSTN-Sim-Intl',
    uuid: '{F4626B2A-E3F6-6BF0-78E7-CBB6123091CB}' },
  { clause: 'LAB-Tansform-Calling',
    description: 'Inbound Transform Calling',
    name: 'CSS-LAB-Transform-Calling',
    uuid: '{70E8D03E-623E-354C-991D-9FB392747291}' },
  { clause: 'AllPhones:Agents:Unity_Connection:UCCX',
    description: 'CSS for UCCX Port Group',
    name: 'CSS-UCCX',
    uuid: '{5FD922AD-9A14-FD17-ACBF-8FAAF2B7326F}' } ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this. I changed my code to match yours and unfortunately, I still receive the same results.

{ css:
   [ '': { cssdescription: 'CSS for UCCX Port Group',
       cssname: 'CSS-UCCX',
       csspartitions: 'AllPhones:Agents:Unity_Connection:UCCX' } ] }

Anything else, you might be able to think of?

Comment: Can you post the whole thing so i can try?

Comment: Absolutely! <Edited>
-----
// MODULES - INCLUDES
var transform = require('camaro');

const xml =` SAME AS ABOVE '

      // HTTP.REQUEST - RESULTS + RENDER
      soapResponse.on('end', () => {
        const { css } = transform(soapreplyx, {
          css: ['//css', {
              cssname: 'name',
              cssdescription: 'description',
              csspartitions: 'clause'
          }]
        });
        console.log(css)
        res.render('cucmmapper-results.html', {
          css: css
        });
      });
    });